# While m exporting data to excel grid lines are not coming

Tags: php, export-to-excel

```
$html='<table style="border: 0.1pt solid #ccc">
        <tr><td>क्षेत्र </td>
            <td>विभाग</td>
            <td>नाम </td>
            <td>पद </td>
            <td>मोबाइल नम्बर </td>
            <td>कोई अन्य नम्बर</td>
            <td>ई-मेल </td>
            <td>पता</td>
        </tr>' ;

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {   
    $html.='<tr>
                <td>'.$row['jila'].' '.$row['vibhag'].' '.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['post'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['mobile1'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['mobile2'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
            </tr>' ;
}
$html.= '</table>';

header('Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=report.xls');
print chr(255) . chr(254) . mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```

Adding table border was mentioned somewhere in a similar post so tried that but still the problem persist. Is there any problem with code due to which this is happening.

Comment: TYPO: `header('Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-exel');` should be `header('Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel');` I believe

Comment: no that change i have made recently.. sorry for that.. but even with that its not working

Comment: Then FIX the code in the question, we can only work with what we see

Comment: Done.. Sorry for that error

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to just output a `.csv` rather than HTML. Excel understands .csv